# Yet another "why won't my divs float" (in jquery-mobile)?

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to make some html code mobile-first, so I've stuck an `@media` to test for "desktop" widths (arbitrarily set to 45em in my sass at the moment). The idea for the two divs (`#picture-block` and `#question-block`) in question is:

```
$desktopwidth: 45em
#question-block, #picture-block
  width: 100%
@media (min-width: $desktopwidth)
  #question-block, #picture-block
    width: 50%
    float: left
```

Despite clicking around in my code inspector, I can only get my two divs in question to float left side-by-side when I kill both `width` properties (50% and 100%). I'm confused by this, because I thought `display: block` would have been the default, and I don't understand why the `width` property would affect the `float`. I'm using the jquery-mobile framework, but I can't see how it would be interfering in the code inspector.

I've created a [codepen link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BoVMwe) to try to replicate the problem. My question: what do I need to do to the css to get the `picture-block` and `question-block` divs to float next to each other for desktop widths?

Comment: For anyone reading this: don't do it this way. Use flex boxes (unless you have to support legacy browsers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the codepen, you also have a 1px border around the blocks. This causes the total width of each to be 50% plus 2 pixels. So two of them won't fit side by side in a 100% container!

Possible solutions:

- either give them `box-sizing:border-box` to include the border width in the width
- or, set the width as `calc(50% - 2px)`

(but not both.)

Comment: Ah, that was it! (I didn't have a border in the actual code, but I did have a few weird padding lines that were screwing it up). Thanks!